# Visualizar quantas pessoas acessaram pdf

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, pdf

Eu tenho um pdf no meu servidor e coloco-o disponível através de um link, existe maneira de controlar quantas pessoas acedem ao pdf?

Comment: voce usa banco de dados?

Comment: Sim uso base de dados em mysql.

Comment: faça um conta cliques ex: if clicknolink update tabela +1

Comment: E caso o link não esteja no site? ou seja caso as pessoas só entrem se eu der o link?

Comment: tente abaixo o que postei

Comment: Sugestão faz um jquery ajax com evento de click e pega a id desse arquivo e faz um arquivo php com update ai cada clique dispara o jquery que faz um ajax nesse arquivo com post ou get

Answer (score 1):

## 1 fase - coletando acessos e exibindo o arquivo

```
// abrir o arquivo através do link do seu servidor
$file = 'file.pdf';
// nome do arquivo
$filename = 'file.pdf'; /* Nota: sempre use .pdf no final. */

// Conectando ao banco
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
// Realizando a query
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE acessos SET contador = contador+1 WHERE `nomearquivo` = $filename);

// exibindo o arquivo
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
```

## 2 fase - ver total de acessos

```
   // essa parte vc pode coloca no local que vai aparecer o total
   $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
   $result = mysqli_query($link, "select contador from acessos where `file` =  $filename);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "$row["contador"]";
    }
```

Comment: Só uma opinião, ao invés de read file, talvez usar while, fgets e feof pode ser melhor para a questão da memória, acredito eu.

Answer (score -2):

Agora se quiser um metodo bem rapido

1º escolha seu codigo num desses que gera online

ex: http://contador.s12.com.br/

2º crie um arquivo ex: contacliques.html

e coloque nele

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://linkdopdf>

codigo do contador que pegou no site
```

so lembrando que isso nao é exato e serve so para ter controle de 1 so arquivo

Comment: caso voce quiser pode mudar o content= o tanto de segundos que vc quer que aparece caso queira visualizar